# Default to ANSI Terminal Emulation in Minicom

Tags: terminal, minicom

Is there a way to default to **ANSI** terminal emulation in `minicom` instead of **VT102** ? Once I'm in `minicom`, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> and then toggle using <kbd>A</kbd>.

```
            This system is restricted to authorized users
          +---------------[Terminal settings]----------------+
          ≠                                                  ≠
          ≠ A -      Terminal emulation : VT102              ≠
          ≠ B -     Backspace key sends : BS                 ≠
          ≠ C -          Status line is : enabled            ≠
          ≠ D -   Newline tx delay (ms) : 0                  ≠
          ≠ E -          ENQ answerback : Minicom2.7         ≠
          ≠ F - Character tx delay (ms) : 0                  ≠
          ≠    Change which setting?                         ≠
          ≠                                                  ≠
          +--------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried `minicom --ansi`, and `minicom --term=ansi` but this neither has an effect.

Answer (score 0):

In your `minicom` config file (`/etc/minirc.x` or `.minirc.x`) put:

```
pu rtscts           Yes
```

Yes for *ANSI*, No for *VT102*.